# substituting a time derivative with a spatial derivative following a Lagrangian approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to follow a derivation for an equation commonly used to calculate the temperature of flowing water.

$$Q=m c_p dT$$

Where $Q$ is heat (J), $m$ is mass (kg), $c_p$ is the specific heat content (J kg-1 K-1), $dT$ is the temperature gradient (K).

$$Q=H A dt$$

Where $H$ is the heat flux (W m-2), A is the surface area (m2) and dt is the time interval (s)

Therefore $\frac{dT}{dt}=\frac{(H A)}{(m c_p)}$

I do not understand the next stage, which says:

This equation can be rewritten by substituting the time derivative with a spatial derivative following a Lagrangian approach, knowing water velocity (v), and following the water parcel, therefore:

$$\frac{d}{dt}=v \frac{d}{dx}$$

And consequently:

$$\frac{dT}{dx}=\frac{(H A)}{(v m c_p)}$$

I will be very grateful if someone can explain to me in the simplest possible terms if this substitution is correct/ possible and, if so, why?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, please make use of MathJax (LaTex renderer on this page)

Comment: @Grace Gamer I've made an attempt to edit your post. Please take a look and correct any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from taking the material derivative of an Eulerian quantity.

Let's say that the fluid velocity field is $u(q,t)$, with $q\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Let's now look at the motion of one particle of fluid $x(t)$; we have that
$$\dot{x}(t) = u[x(t)]$$

Now suppose that the fluid has some property (heat, say) that we want to track. This heat can be written as function $f(q,t)$ over the fluid domain.

If we want to measure *how $f$ changes for one particular particle of fluid* we take the derivative
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x[t],t) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x[t],t) + \nabla_q f(x[t],t)\cdot \dot x(t)\\
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x[t],t) + \nabla_q f(x[t],t)\cdot u(x[t],t)
\end{align*}

How the above applies to your problem will depend on details which aren't clear in your post: but for example if $f$ measures the steady-state temperature of flowing water, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=0$ and you get your "following the water parcel" equation.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this conceptually. What information would you need to apply this to my problem?